# Calling a restful web service (non SOAP) with java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, jax-ws-customization

I'm trying to develop, using Java, a simple application that call a web-service restful which returns an xml and then I need to provide the result to a jsp page. 
I was thinking to use CXF but what is not clear is the fact that the restful service can have different urls with parameters like:

http://ws-host.com/rest/products?BRAND=020&LOCALE=en_gb?product_code=600200

http://ws-host.com/rest/products?BRAND=020&LOCALE=en_gb&VEHICLE_BRAND=test

or

http://ws-host.com/rest/dealers?BRAND=020&LOCALCE=en_gb&SEARCH_TERM=Test

How can I do that? I'm a bit confused.
Thanks

Comment: What is your question by the way?

Comment: What's your confusion about ?

Comment: Is it possible that I need to use wadl2java or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

CXF supports [JSR-339 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) so you can use this API to create your mappings with different parameters.

You can use `@QueryParam` annotation, [here is an example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/)